# Should I use mixed or individual data in a mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have a schema for an order, what would be a better design, this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    timePlaced: Date,
    packageDimensions: {height: Number, width: Number, weight: Number }
})
```

Or this

```
var schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    timePlaced: Date,
    height: Number, 
    width: Number, 
    weight: Number
})
```

Comment: This is a matter of choice/application design/style. There's no correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no compelling reason to make a subdocument for such a small amount of data.

With mongoose, you could increase the speed (read: reduce CPU usage) of your queries by excluding packageDimensions (if it was a subdocument) from the conversion to JSON. But since it's only 4 lines, I can't see it having a huge impact.

Save yourself some extra typing. Stick with a flatter style until you have a good reason to do otherwise.